# Display problems being faced in firefox

Tags: vb.net, firefox, firebug

I have a list of tags which when clicked, display a page which contains more info about that particular tag. In fact, it describes it in detail, in a i-frame .

The issue i am facing is that, when my firebug version 1.5.4 is enabled the details ares displayed but when i disable the Firebug, the details do not get displayed.

the coding has been done in vb.net

my browser is firefox v 3.6.8

I was looking for ideas on how i should go about fixing this issue.

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing some code - a live link would be better. Is the HTML valid?

Answer (score 1):

One common way that "Firebug fixes buggy pages" is when developers use `window.console()` (or just `console` functions) in JavaScript development and then deploy without guarding the calls -- EG: `if (window.console)`.